# Найти неизвестную вершину треугольника

Tags: математика, геометрия

Каков порядок действий, чтобы решить данную задачку?

> У нас есть *прямоугольный треугольник* **ABC** на плоскости координат. Нам известны координаты точки **A** и точки **B**, а так же расстояние между точками **BC**. Мы так же можем найти длину гипотенузы, по этому длина гипотенузы нам так же известна. Необходимо найти точку **C**.

[image: треугольник]

Comment: Длина BC известна. Длина AB считается, так что тоже известна. Раз он прямоугольный, что AC тоже можно посчитать. Дальше составляешь систему из 2 уравнений с 2 неизвестными (x и y точки С) и решаешь её, получая 2 варианта для точки С.

Comment: @Akina а можно по подробнее? Наглядно было бы более понятнее

Comment: [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Ваш вопрос - явный оффтоп.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, есть два условия - длина BC и теорема Пифагора, т.е.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если не ошибся, ее решение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Отнимем ото всех точек координаты B. Теперь B находится в нуле, и уравнения будут немного проще.

Для расстояния B-C

```
cx^2 + cy^2 = BC^2
```

Перпендикулярность отрезков - скалярное произведение векторов нулевое

```
(cx-ax)*cx + (cy-ay)*cy = 0
```

Решаем систему, получаем два возможных решения для `(cx,cy)`.

Добавляем исходные координаты B.

Answer (score 1):

Как вам правильно подсказали в коментариях алгоритм следующий:

```
BC^2 + AC^2 = AB^2 // по теореме Пифагора
AC = Sqrt(AB^2-BC^2);
```

У нас есть две окружности с центрами `А` и `В`  радиусами `АС` и `ВС` соответственно:

```
(Cx – Ax)^2 + (Cy – Ay)^2 = AC^2
(Cx – Bx)^2 + (Cy – By)^2 = BC^2
```

Получаем систему уравнений с двумя переменными.
Можем выразить Сy в верхнем увравнении и подставить в нижнее.
Очевидно что эти окружности пересекаются в двух точках поэтому получим два варианта для С.